# JavaFX First Person Centering Mouse

Tags: javafx

I am trying to learn about programming 3D in javafx. My goal is to lock the cursor in the center or move it to the center for a first person view.

I made a mouse moved event and I move the cursor to the middle of the screen, then change the camera depending on where I moved the mouse to. The problem is that whenever it moves the cursor back to the center the event fires again reversing the change in camera angle. Anyone know a way to make it so when it moves the cursor back to the center it doesn't affect the camera angle?

```
    scene.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
        int screenWidth = (int) Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth();
        int screenHeight = (int) Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getHeight();
        moveCursor(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2);
        double dx = mouseX - e.getSceneX();
        double dy = mouseY - e.getSceneY();
        mouseX = e.getSceneX();
        mouseY = e.getSceneY();
        camAngleX += dx / 10;
        camAngleY -= dy / 10;
    });
```

Here is after adding the Boolean check...
I defined "ignoreMouseMove" somewhere else.

```
    scene.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
        if (ignoreMouseMove) {
            ignoreMouseMove = false;
        } else {
            double cx = primaryStage.getX() + scene.getX() + sceneX / 2;
            double cy = primaryStage.getY() + scene.getY() + sceneY / 2;
            double dx = mouseX - e.getSceneX();
            double dy = mouseY - e.getSceneY();
            mouseX = e.getSceneX();
            mouseY = e.getSceneY();
            camAngleX += dx / 10;
            camAngleY -= dy / 10;
            ignoreMouseMove = true;
            moveMouse(cx, cy);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a boolean check like:

```
boolean ignoreMouseMove = false;

scene.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
    if(ignoreMouseMove) {
        ignoreMouseMove = false;
    } else {
        int screenWidth = (int) Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth();
        int screenHeight = (int) Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getHeight();
        ignoreMouseMove = true;
        moveCursor(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2);
        double dx = mouseX - e.getSceneX();
        double dy = mouseY - e.getSceneY();
        mouseX = e.getSceneX();
        mouseY = e.getSceneY();
        camAngleX += dx / 10;
        camAngleY -= dy / 10;
    }
});
```

If it helps you here is an implementation I did myself a few weeks back that works:

```
Robot mouseMover = new Robot(); //defined somewhere else

scene.setOnMouseMoved(event -> {
    if(ignoreMouseEvent) {
        ignoreMouseEvent = false;
        return;
    }

    mouseDeltaX += Math.round(event.getScreenX() - (stage.getX() + (stage.getWidth() / 2.0))) / 5.0;
    mouseDeltaY += -Math.round((event.getScreenY() - (stage.getY() + (stage.getHeight() / 2.0)))) / 5.0;

    ignoreMouseEvent = true;
    mouseMover.mouseMove((int) (stage.getX() + (stage.getWidth() / 2.0)), (int) (stage.getY() + (stage.getHeight() / 2.0)));
});
```

Comment: I added the boolean check like you said and it still didn't work

Comment: So you are still getting the behavior of `mouseEvents` calling themselves recursively an infinite amount of time?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example that I implemented myself.